# How to parse it into a hashmap back

Tags: java

I have a problem: I want to return a sorted `hashmap` but unfortunatelly it isnt a hasmap anymore. How could I parse it back to a `hashmap` ?

```
private HashMap<int[], Double> sortHashMap(HashMap<int[], Double> hashMap) {
            HashMap<int[], Double>  sortedHashMap = new HashMap<int[], Double>();
            List<Entry<int[], Double>> list = new ArrayList<>(hashMap.entrySet());
            list.sort(Entry.comparingByValue());
            // sortedHashMap = list.sort(Entry.comparingByValue()); // not working :(
            return sortedHashMap;
        }
```

Comment: There is no such thing as a ordered HashMap: [This class makes no guarantees as to the order of the map; in particular, it does not guarantee that the order will remain constant over time.](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/HashMap.html). If you want your data to be ordered, use a different Map type.

Comment: use `TreeMap` if you want sorted map

Comment: Also: Having an `int[]` array as the Map key and a `Double` as the value seems kind of strange design. Are you sure it shouldn't be the other way around where you map a `Double` key to an `int[]` array value?

Comment: @O-9 thank you very much for the answer but could you maybe write the code for my understanding? that would be very helpfull

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just sorting the list using `sort` will not give you back a map. You also cannot use a `HashMap` to build a sorted map. Use a [`LinkedHashMap`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/util/LinkedHashMap.html) to preserve the order when collecting the entries of the list:

```
private LinkedHashMap<int[], Double> sortHashMap(HashMap<int[], Double> hashMap) {
    List<Entry<int[], Double>> list = new ArrayList<>(hashMap.entrySet());
    list.sort(Entry.comparingByValue());
    return list.stream().collect(Collectors.toMap(Entry::getKey, Entry::getValue,
            (key1, key2) -> key2, LinkedHashMap::new));
}
```

Note that the third argument, `(key1, key2) -> key2` is the merge function in case there are duplicate keys found by the collector (which should not happen in this case).

Comment: Thank you very much for your help! but is there a chance to get the keys of the best values back? If there are more then 2 best values, then the programm also should return 2 keys. That would be very kind of you.

Comment: @Kazim If you're sorting by value, a simple for loop can do it. Using streams, you can also use [`Stream.limit`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/util/stream/Stream.html#limit(long)). If you need to reverse the comparison, use [`Comparator.reversed()`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/util/Comparator.html#reversed()).